# regex: find a line somewhere after another line

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to find a specific line in a file that occurs somewhere after another line.  for example, I may want to find the string "friend", but only when it occurs on a line after a line containing the string "hello".  so for example:

```
hello there
how are you
my friend
```

should pass, but

```
how are you
my friend
hello
```

or

```
hello friend
how are you
```

should not pass.

The only thing I've thought of is something like `hello[.\s]*\n[.\s]*friend`, which does not work.

EDIT: I'm using a customized program that has a lot of limitations.  I don't have access to switches or custom modes.  I need a single regular expression that works for the standard python regex mode.

Comment: `hello.*?friend` you could try this with `s` flag

Comment: see edit. I dont have access to modes

Comment: `hello\s+(?!friend)[\n\s\S]+?friend` check this once.

Answer (score 2):

`hello[.\s]*\n[.\s]*friend`

First note that a dot inside a character class matches for a literal dot, not as a "match all" character, so you really want alternation, not character class for this.  But also not that a "match all" dot will also match spaces, so you don't even need alternation.

So overall, you really just need this:

`hello.*?friend`

Now comes the problem with matching across new-line chars. By default the "match all" dot does not match new-line chars.  You can flag/modifier it to match it, but how you do that depends on what language you are using. In php or perl, you can use the `s` modifier, e.g.

**php:**

```
preg_match('~hello.*?friend~s',$content);
```

**edit:**

If you are trying to use regex in something like an editor (or otherwise can't add flags/modifiers), most editors have an option to flag it as such.  If not, you can try alternation with newline chars like so:

`hello(.|\r?\n)*friend`

Comment: Thanks, but see the edit to the question. Unfortunately I can't use modifiers. It needs to work for the standard mode

Comment: @ewok also, can you please provide more context for where/how you are actually using the regex then? e.g. what language, program, framework, etc..?

Comment: Its a custom proprietary program, but the regular expression is executed in python with no flags.

Comment: I did. It didn't pass. I'll have to email the people who wrote the program and see if I can see the actual code. It may not be possible.

Comment: @ewok okay well they may possibly be doing something internally like escaping characters.  You can try playing with escaping some of the characters, e.g. `hello(.|\\r?\\n)*friend` but at this point you're just making guesses to what's inside that blackbox. I agree, you should contact the people who wrote the program

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Hands for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to include two newline characters.

```
hello(?:.*\n)+.*friend
```

This expects atleast one newline character present inbetween.

Comment: what do I do if I dont know how many lines will be between the two strings?

Comment: I said "when it occurs on a line after".  I didnt specify exactly one line.  it can be any number of lines

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means a regex expert (particularly not in Python), but my RegexBuddy app thinks this will work:

```
(?s)hello.*\n+.*friend
```

The `(?s)` is apparently an inline way of specifying the "Dot matches newline" option, which seems to be necessary for the \n to work.